# can i set a callback for when constraintLayout animation has finished

Tags: android

I've just started to learn animations and I'm trying to add another view after the constraint layout change animation has finished.
I added a listener for when the constraint layout has changed but that fires when the animation has started, not after it has completed.

```
        rootConstraintLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLayoutChange: testing ");
            }
        });
```

**this is the method I call to change the layout**

```
    private void changeExamplePageLayout() {

        ConstraintSet constraintSetBeforeExample = new ConstraintSet();
        ConstraintSet constraintSetAfterExample = new ConstraintSet();

        constraintSetBeforeExample.clone(rootConstraintLayout);

        constraintSetAfterExample.clone(getContext(), R.layout.example_fragment_sub_set);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootConstraintLayout);

        constraintSetAfterExample.applyTo(rootConstraintLayout);

    }
```

any direction into what I should look at will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

So i solved this,

Instead of this code here =

```
rootConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.rootConstraintLayout);

constraintSetBeforeExample = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSetAfterExample = new ConstraintSet();


constraintSetBeforeExample.clone(rootConstraintLayout);
constraintSetAfterExample.clone(getContext(),R.layout.example_fragment_sub_set);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootConstraintLayout);
```

Where the Transition manager uses a default transition if you dont provide one in the delayedTransition method, i created my own transition to which you can add a listener to.

```
rootConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.rootConstraintLayout);

constraintSetBeforeExample = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSetAfterExample = new ConstraintSet();


constraintSetBeforeExample.clone(rootConstraintLayout);
constraintSetAfterExample.clone(getContext(),R.layout.example_fragment_sub_set);


Transition transition = new ChangeBounds();

transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(@NonNull Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(@NonNull Transition transition) {

            if (layoutChanged) {

                addExampleQuestionFragment();

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(@NonNull Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(@NonNull Transition transition) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(@NonNull Transition transition) {

        }
    });
```

Then set the transition youve just created as a argument in the method

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootConstraintLayout, transition);
```

Hope his helps if anyone else has this issue

Comment: Really helpful.  Thanks for posting this.